# Is it possible to use vidstabdetect and vidstabtransform together in ffmpeg's -filter_complex option?

Tags: ffmpeg, filtering, video-processing

I'm wondering if it is possible to use the `vidstabdetect` and `vidstabtransform` filters together in the `-filter_complex` option, in one `ffmpeg ...` command? If it is, a simple example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `vidstabtransform` filter reads the entire analyzed data at time of initialization so the data has to be complete at that time.